# Javascript: Calling child function from parent (super?) function.

Tags: javascript, inheritance, prototype-programming

Both parent functions are overridden by child. two in the child is calling parent's two. however, i was expecting that at the parent level, the call to one would invoke the child's method. Is there a concept that i am missing?

Thank you in advance!

http://jsfiddle.net/9mbGN/

```
function parent(){}

parent.prototype.one = function(){
    $('body').append("Parent: one <br/>");
}

parent.prototype.two = function(){
    this.one();
    $('body').append("Parent: two <br/>");
}


function child(){}

child.prototype = new parent();
child.prototype.constructor = child;

child.prototype.one = function(){ //should this function not be called? 
    $('body').append('Child: one <br />');
}

child.prototype.two = function(){
    $('body').append('Child: do some child stuff here and call parent: <br />');
    parent.prototype.two();    
}



var k = new child();
k.two();
```

Comment: `this.one()` calls `parent.prototype.one()` in your child's `two()` because `this` is `parent.prototype`

Comment: Is there any way to call the child.prototype.one?

Comment: Just call `child.prototype.one()` ? I'm unsure of what you're actually trying to do. What is this all for?

Comment: but does that not defeat the purpose of inheritance?

Comment: Why not simply `parent.prototype.two.call(this)` ?

Comment: @JoeSimmons That's not true, this.one is the last value of `one` at `this` prototype chain, and that is `child.prototype.one. `this` is an object than prototypes `child.prototype` than prototypes `parent.prototype`

Comment: @A.MatíasQuezada: I can't understand you.

Comment: @JoeSimmons you said `this.one()` calls `parent.prototype.one` at chil's `two()` because `this` is `parent.prototype`. That's not true, `this` is an object than prototypes `child.prototype` so `this.one` refeers to `child.prototype.one`

Comment: When you call `parent.prototype.two()` 'this' will be `parent.prototype`

Comment: My fault, you're right, sorry :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The more optimal way is almost like you are doing it, but you call the parent method over `this`:

```
child.prototype.two = function(arg1, arg2) {
  parent.prototype.two.call(this, arg1, arg2);
};
```

But I recommend you to use a custom function to extend, you can use `extend` from **[jsbase](https://github.com/amatiasq/jsbase/blob/master/src/extend.js)**

If you are using ECMAScript 5 getters/setters (if not just use the first one) you may prefeer to use the one at **[this gist](https://gist.github.com/amatiasq/5619166)**

Both can be used the same way based on Dean Edward's idea:

```
var Animal = extend(Object, {

  constructor: function(name) {
    // Invoke Object's constructor
    this.base();

    this.name = name;

    // Log creation
    console.log('New animal named ' + name);
  },

  // Abstract
  makeSound: function() {
    console.log(this.name + ' is going to make a sound :)');
  },

});

var Dog = Animal.extend({

  constructor: function(name) {
    // Invoke Animals's constructor
    this.base(name);

    // Log creation
    console.log('Dog instanciation');
  },

  bark: function() {
    console.log('WOF!!!');
  },

  makeSound: function() {
    this.base();
    this.bark();
  }
});

var pet = new Dog('buddy');
// New animal named buddy
// Dog instanciation
pet.makeSound();
// buddy is going to make a sound :)
// WOF!!!
```

In your case it can be:

```
var parent = extend(Object, {
  one: function() {
    $('body').append("Parent: one <br/>");
  },
  two: function() {
    this.one();
    $('body').append("Parent: two <br/>");
  }
});

var child = parent.extend({
  one: function() {
    $('body').append('Child: one <br />');
  },
  two: function() {
    $('body').append('Child: do some child stuff here and call parent: <br />');
    this.base();
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, I understand what you want...
define you function like this:

```
child.prototype.two = (function(){
if(child.prototype.two){
   var tmp = child.prototype.two;
   return function(){
   $('body').append('Child: do some child stuff here and call parent: <br />');   
   tmp.apply(this,arguments);
   };
  }
})()
```

You could add else condition to return a function if there is no same function defined on prototype.

Answer (score 0):

Answered by slebetman:

`parent.prototype.two.call(this)`

Instead of directly invoking the parent's two function.